# Keras for 3D CNN with binary images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use a 3D CNN for 3D binary images (black and white with all values as 0 or 1). Because it is black and white, there is no "4th" dimension for color channels and the data shape is (256, 256, 124). How would I build the CNN in keras? Would I use Conv3d still or change to Conv2D?

Comment: you reshape your input arrays to have a single channel. The rest should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

First things first both 2D CNN and 3D CNN can work. You just need to get the right shape for your data but you need to understand the difference between 2D CNN and 3D CNN:

- In 2D CNN your filter moves in only two dimensions of the image which means that the third dimension of your filter must be 124 the same as the image (in keras you don't have to set it manually the framework sets it for you).
- In 3D CNN you allow the filter to move in the third dimension of the image so your filter third dimension can be less than or equals to 124

Finally binary images is too simple to use 3D Conv with it. Your model will overfit the data. Use 2D CNN instead

Comment: Thanks. Is the input size of 256x256x124 too large, if so should i perform cropping on the input images?

Comment: No it's not too large, but the model most probably will fit the data. You will have to add regularizers, dropout or making the model simpler ..etc